# Handling browser logout functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im planning to handle logout functionality with my website ie; Once the browser hits the logout button and he clicks back or refresh button he needs to be redirected to the login page of my website...

Is it possible to do that?

I'm planning to use the below code in one of the blog..

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
function ClearHistory()
{
     var backlen = history.length;
     history.go(-backlen);
     window.location.href = loggedOutPageUrl
}
</SCRIPT>
```

I would like to know if I can clear the browser history specific to my browser...I dont want to destroy the whole history?

Comment: You can't "clear the cache" programmatically. If you explain what you're trying to achieve by doing that, you might get a better answer.

Comment: Sounds like XY problem

Comment: BTW, it looks like you want to clear browser's history not cache. So really, you'd have better to explain what you are looking for

Comment: THanks Wolff and Pointy at your response...I have updated my question..

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't "clear the cache" with Javascript. The best way forward here is to ensure that those sensitive pages never make their way into the cache in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear the cache with javascript.